# The scroll bar in windows of mozilla firefox is automatically moving

Tags: firefox

The control of mouse scroll wheel is lost. The scroll bar is moving up and down automatically. I have reinstalled mozilla. Still the problem exists.

Comment: Have you tried reset firefox ? Please provide more information about what are you occurring.

Comment: How to reset firefox?

Comment: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/refresh-firefox-reset-add-ons-and-settings

Comment: DId you spill anything on your keyboard / mouse recently.It could also be a virus (though never heard of one like this on Linux) or a prank / annoyance set up by someone else

Comment: Nothing of that sort. If it is a virus, I have installed ClamTk antivirus installed.